# Recommended way to do asynchronous actions in redux in angular 2

Tags: angular, redux

I use [ng-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux) module in angular 2 and I don't know what is the better way to do asynchronous actions. For example I need to fetch some data from server. I can do it using async action creator [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware:
I will create an action that returns a function:

```
export function fetchData() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST'
        });
        return fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch({type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS', data: json}))
            .catch(error => dispatch({type: 'FETCH_DATA_ERROR', error: error
        }
    }
}
dispatch(fetchData());
```

Or I can do the HTTP request in controller and I will manually execute dispatch method:

```
dispatch({
    type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST'
});
http(url).then(data => {
     dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
        data: json
    });
}).catch(error => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_ERROR',
        error: error
    });
});
```

Which method is recommended? I think that the second method is easier, but why then redux-thunk middleware exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the first method is what is recommended, especially if you're using a middleware library.

<strike>Only thing to remember is to dispatch your action inside the `ComponentDidMount` React lifecycle method.</strike>

Comment: The question was related to angular not react.